# Nonlinear optimization - do I have to enter constraints?

Tags: r, optimization, nlopt

I have an optimization problem with no constraints (at least none for now). I'm wondering if the error I'll describe arises from not specifying any constraints? I wouldn't think so.

I have a function with two arguments, `lagg` and `thres`

I have a vector of zeros and ones representing recession dates. I want to manipulate an economic time series (turning it into zeros and ones) and get it as close to "dating" recessions as possible.

Here is the function, which is passed to `eval_f` hoping to maximize the F1 score.

```
fxn_unsmoothed2 <- function(input)
{ lagg <- input[1]
  thres <- input[2]
  truth <- data.matrix(USREC[-1:-lagg,])
chng <- percentchange(goodsmtx,lagg)
chng[chng<thres] <- 1
chng[chng!=1] <- 0
FP <- length(which(chng==1 & truth==0))
FN <- length(which(chng==0 & truth==1))
TP <- length(which(chng==1 & truth==1))
TN <- length(which(chng==0 & truth==0))
return (2*(TP/(TP+FP))*(TP/(TP+FN)) / ((TP/(TP+FP))+(TP/(TP+FN))))
}
```

The whole `input[1]` thing is confusing to me. I saw it on a separate post.
I then do

```
x0 <- c(11,.005)
opts <- list("algorithm"="NLOPT_GN_ISRES",maxeval=100000)
res <- nloptr( x0=x0,
               eval_f=fxn_unsmoothed2,
               opts=opts)
```

It runs zero iterations and tells me:

> NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS: Invalid arguments (e.g. lower bounds are bigger than upper bounds, an unknown
> algorithm was specified, etcetera

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. At least I finally figured out how to pass initial arguments, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you have to specify *some* reasonable constraints (the range could be very broad). You could also switch optimizers, but you would have to move out of the "GN" (global, derivative-free) class: according to the [NLopt documentation](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms)

> All of the global-optimization algorithms currently require you to specify bound constraints on all the optimization parameters.

(I usually use "NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA" for derivative-free optimization. Or you could use `optim(..., method = "Nelder-Mead")` from base R.)

You didn't give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ...  Using the example from `?nloptr::isres`, which is a convenient wrapper for the `NLOPT_GN_ISRES` optimizer (you can look at the source code to see, it's not very complicated):

This (example as given) works fine:

```r
library(nloptr)
fn <- function(x)
         return( 100 * (x[2] - x[1] * x[1])^2 + (1 - x[1])^2 )
x0 <- c( -1.2, 1 )
lb <- c( -3, -3 )
ub <- c(  3,  3 )
isres(x0 = x0, fn = fn, lower = lb, upper = ub)
```

If I try to leave out the bounds it complains:

```r
isres(x0 = x0, fn = fn)
```

> argument "lower" is missing, with no default

If I do this "raw" I get the same behaviour you saw:

```r
opts <- list("algorithm"="NLOPT_GN_ISRES",maxeval=100000)
res <- nloptr( x0=x0,
               eval_f=fn,
               opts=opts)
```

If I try to set the limits to `-Inf`/`+Inf` (which works for `optim()`):

```r
isres(x0 = x0, fn = fn, lower = rep(-Inf, 2), upper = rep(Inf, 2))
```

I also get an "NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS" error.

If I specify finite but ridiculously large bounds, the optimizer [silently!] fails (does all the iterations requested, but stays stuck at the starting point):

```r
isres(x0 = x0, fn = fn, lower = rep(-1e9, 2), upper = rep(1e9, 2))
```

However, if I use bounds that are way larger than the original choice (±100 instead of ±3) it gives reasonable answers, although not quite as precise as the original fit:

```r
isres(x0 = x0, fn = fn, lower = rep(-100, 2), upper = rep(100, 2))
```